# Simple SQL update query takes forever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query generated by Linq

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[VStat]
set [VStatName] = @0, [VStatEnum] = @1, [VStatDownload] = @2, [VStatUpdateTime] = @3, [VStatShowInReport] = @4, [VStatShowInFleetReport] = @5, [VStatShowInMonitoringReport] = @6, [VStatShowInMobileApp] = @7
where ([VStatId] = @8)
',N'@0 nvarchar(50),@1 decimal(18,0),@2 bit,@3 datetime2(7),@4 bit,@5 bit,@6 bit,@7 bit,@8 uniqueidentifier',@0=N'Actif',@1=1,@2=1,@3='2016-08-16 12:39:01.4753654',@4=1,@5=1,@6=1,@7=1,@8='3A124BBA-6ECB-46A8-8932-06D24E55E3B9'
```

The query is pretty simple but when I run it it never ends. So I can't look at the execution plan. The table is also pretty simple. Basically all the columns are shown in the query.

The table has three indexes:

- `IX_VStat` (clustered) - nvarchar(50)
- `IX_VStat_VStatShowInReport` (non-unique, non-clustered)
- `PX_VStat` (Unique, Non-Clustered) - uniqueidentifier

I found the way to fix the query but not sure how it works and if it's ever correct

I disabled index `IX_VStat` (clustered) and then rebuilt it. After that the query started working pretty fast.

When I disabled the index `IX_VStat` (clustered), I got a hole bunch of warnings:

> Warning: Clustered index 'IX_InsObservId' on view 'InsObservView'
>   referencing table 'VStat' was disabled as a result of disabling the
>   index 'IX_VStat'.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_InsId' on view 'InsObservView' was disabled as a
>   result of disabling the clustered index on the view.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_InsFlId_ShowInReport_InsEndTime_TyId' on view
>   'InsObservView' was disabled as a result of disabling the clustered
>   index on the view.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_InsLocId_ShowInReport_InsEndTime_TyId' on view
>   'InsObservView' was disabled as a result of disabling the clustered
>   index on the view.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_VFlId_ShowInReport_InsEndTime_TyId' on view
>   'InsObservView' was disabled as a result of disabling the clustered
>   index on the view.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_VLocId_ShowInReport_InsEndTime_TyId' on view
>   'InsObservView' was disabled as a result of disabling the clustered
>   index on the view.
>
> Warning: Clustered index 'IX_Index' on view 'TyLifeReport' referencing
>   table 'VStat' was disabled as a result of disabling the index
>   'IX_VStat'.
>
> Warning: Clustered index 'IX_Index' on view 'tc_support_V' referencing
>   table 'VStat' was disabled as a result of disabling the index
>   'IX_VStat'.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_FlId_Stat' on view 'tc_support_V' was disabled as a
>   result of disabling the clustered index on the view.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_LocId_VId' on view 'tc_support_V' was disabled as a
>   result of disabling the clustered index on the view.
>
> Warning: Clustered index 'IX_Index' on view 'MinTrDepView' referencing
>   table 'VStat' was disabled as a result of disabling the index
>   'IX_VStat'.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_InsFlId_InsDate' on view 'MinTrDepView' was
>   disabled as a result of disabling the clustered index on the view.
>
> Warning: Index 'IX_InsId_TrDep' on view 'MinTrDepView' was disabled as
>   a result of disabling the clustered index on the view.
>
> ... a dozen more here.

So there are many relations to this table. The majority of them are from views.

Please help with advice)

Comment: Please provide est execution plan and view definition with triggers

Answer (score 0):

May be you should redesign your database and use surrogated (int, bigin or uniqueidentifier) primary key instead of nvarchar(50)? So, all foreign keys will reference this key and index on string value always slower. You can add non clustered index on nvarchar(50) field.

Also add maintenance tasks to reorganize indexes if you have a lot of rows in table and more or less big traffic in it